# foreign key constraints. can child table have null values? ERROR 1452 (23000)

Tags: mysql, database-design, null, foreign-keys

I have a controlled vocabulary table set up as such:

```
-- create the film_stock table
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS film_stock;
CREATE TABLE film_stock (
    stock varchar (10) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(stock))
    ENGINE = INNODB;
```

There are only two values assigned to 'stock' - Nitrate and Acetate.

'stock' serves as a foreign key in my table films:

```
-- create the films table
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS films;
CREATE TABLE films (
    title varchar (100) NOT NULL,
    alternate_title varchar (50) NULL,
    year_of_release varchar (15) NULL,  
    country varchar (50) NULL,
    running_time_minutes int (10) NULL,
    footage_lenght_feet int (10) NULL,
    stock varchar (10) NULL,
    gauge varchar (10) NULL,
    bw_color varchar (10) NULL,
    notes varchar (255) NULL,
    print_publications varchar (255) NULL,
    existent_print varchar (255) NULL,
    url_1 varchar (100) NULL,
    url_2 varchar (100) NULL,
    url_3 varchar (100) NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(title),
    FOREIGN KEY(country) REFERENCES countries (country),
    FOREIGN KEY(stock) REFERENCES film_stock (stock),
    FOREIGN KEY(gauge) REFERENCES film_gauge (gauge),
    FOREIGN KEY(bw_color) REFERENCES bw_or_color (bw_color))
    ENGINE = INNODB;
```

In this films table the column 'stock' if often empty because I don't yet know what the film stock is for any particular film.

I'm getting this error when I run the script:

```
ERROR 1452 (23000): Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`hbm248_BucherFilms1`.`films`, CONSTRAINT `films_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`stock`) REFERENCES `film_stock` (`stock`))
```

Am I not allowed to have empty values in my films table when the foreign key it is referencing doesn't have empty values? I thought setting 'stock' to NULL in the films table would allow empty values... Or do I need to set stock to NULL in the film_stock table as well? Right now it is NOT NULL...
Or do I need to enter in some value like 'unknown' into the controlled vocab table 'stock' and then populate the stock column in films with this 'unknown' value and change it at a later date when I'm certain the stock is either Nitrate or Acetate?
This last option seems like it would solve my problems but also feels like it should be unnecessary and there should be a way for MySQL to allow empty values in the film table.

Thanks!

Comment: Will the stock column in film_stock be unique?

Comment: yes (well i think so if I understand your use of unique)

Comment: the two values, nitrate and acetate, will only be in that column.

Comment: With that being the case, making the column accept nulls would break the uniqueness.  One option would be to create a temporary placeholder in your film_stock table. Once the stock value has been established for a film, you could then update that records value to the appropriate stock information.  Side Note: To make things easier you may want to add a int primary key and add that value to a stockId field in films.

Comment: I thought about the temporary place holder idea, but ugh, I was hoping not to have to do that as it seem like a bunch of extra, unnecessary work.  I just want stock in the films table to accept a NULL value...

Comment: You could do that, however you would need to drop the FK.

Comment: Really? Damn. Then how do I go about setting up a controlled vocabulary table?

Comment: It really depends upon how complex you would like to make it.  Allow me to demonstrate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can child table have null values?

This is not possible with current FK relationship.  The sections below will provide guidance on setting up a vocabulary list.

**Vocabulary list with Multiple Tables**

Create a table for each list using an ID for PK.  This ID will then used used as a FK on other tables.

```
CREATE TABLE film_stock (
  `ID` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,  
  stock varchar (10) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(ID))
ENGINE = INNODB;
```

> and repeat for each list...

**Alternative Way with a single table**

```
CREATE TABLE VocabularyList (
  `ID` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,  
  groupName varchar (10) NOT NULL,
  groupValue varchar (50) NOT NULL,
  groupOrder int NOT NULL Default 0,
    PRIMARY KEY(ID))
ENGINE = INNODB;
```

**Insert statement for VocabularyList**

```
insert into VocabularyList(groupName, groupValue, groupOrder) VALUES ('DefaultValue','Pending_Value',1);

insert into VocabularyList(groupName, groupValue, groupOrder) VALUES ('stock','nitrate',1);

insert into VocabularyList(groupName, groupValue, groupOrder) VALUES ('stock','acetate',2);
```

**Query to retrieve stock information from VocabularyList**

```
select groupValue
from VocabularyList
where groupName = 'stock'
order by groupOrder
```

**Updated films table using single table alternative**

```
CREATE TABLE films (
    title varchar (100) NOT NULL,
    alternate_title varchar (50) NULL,
    year_of_release varchar (15) NULL,  
    countryID int NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
    running_time_minutes int (10) NULL,
    footage_lenght_feet int (10) NULL,
    stockID int NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
    gaugeID int NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
    bw_colorID int NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
    notes varchar (255) NULL,
    print_publications varchar (255) NULL,
    existent_print varchar (255) NULL,
    url_1 varchar (100) NULL,
    url_2 varchar (100) NULL,
    url_3 varchar (100) NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(title),
    FOREIGN KEY(countryID) REFERENCES VocabularyList(ID),
    FOREIGN KEY(stockID) REFERENCES VocabularyList(ID),
    FOREIGN KEY(gaugeID) REFERENCES VocabularyList(ID),
    FOREIGN KEY(bw_colorID) REFERENCES VocabularyList(ID))
    ENGINE = INNODB;
```

*For ease of use, the films table primary key could be switched to an int datatype.  This will ensure PK uniqueness and reduced keystrokes.*